# chown and chmod doesn't work (Raspberry Pi 2 - Jessie)

Tags: linux, permissions, raspberry-pi, raspbian, rights

I would like to make a fileserver at home using Raspberry Pi 2.
Currently there are 3 users: root, pi and alma.
My connected external drive is mounted automatically to /media/pi/TOURO
I would like to share "Share" directory on this drive for "alma" users (with read+write permissions)

The problem is that when I try to change owner of the "Share" dir nothing happens:

```
pi@raspberrypi /media/pi/TOURO $ ls -l
drwx------ 1 pi pi     0 Nov  6 16:40 Share
pi@raspberrypi /media/pi/TOURO $ sudo chown -R alma:alma Share
pi@raspberrypi /media/pi/TOURO $ ls -l
drwx------ 1 pi pi     0 Nov  6 16:40 Share
```

If I try to change permissions of the directory the same happens:

```
pi@raspberrypi /media/pi/TOURO $ sudo chmod 777 Share
pi@raspberrypi /media/pi/TOURO $ ls -l
drwx------ 1 pi pi     0 Nov  6 16:40 Share
```

Has anyone faced with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after "permissions" option was added in fstab.
Like this line:

```
UUID=741E3B271E3AE232 /media/TOURO ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
```

After this I can chown my files and directories on external drive.